# Intellij watch panel shows wrong datatypes for variables during debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Tried uploading some screenshot, but for some reason get "forbidden error message". So i will try to explain it without screenshots.

I am using IntelliJ 2021.1.2 and BigSur Mac OS. When I debug my program, the Watches pane shows incorrect datatypes of my watch variables. For example if I have:

```
List<List<String>> allBatches
```

But in watches its shown as List of booleans, it even shows entries as [true,true,true,false,false].

Anybody faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of watch window?

Comment: i am trying to find some service to upload an image, which is surprisingly difficult from a work env where everything is locked. And stackoverflow shows me "forbidden" error when i try to upload directly from my computer

Comment: try imgur. maybe it is not locked.